# TinyMCE get node CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am building an app which uses *TinyMCE* to edit contents in TD blocks. Function **tinyMCE.execCommand(...)** is binded to many custom buttons, these buttons are not built with *TinyMCE ControllManager*, they are just some DIVs with onClick event, which sends *execCommand* to *tinyMCE*.

When editing content with default *TinyMCE* buttons, they show the current state of the node. E.g. we click in a bold, italic text of ordered list - we can see button "B"," I" and "OL" are active in the controls. I need to do something similar - get attributes of current node, so I can add some class to my custom buttons.

There is **handle_node_change_callback** , where I should get these attributes. Does *TinyMCE* have some built-in function that shows current node properties?

What i expect it to be: node.getAllProperties() returns ['Bold', 'Italic', 'OrderedList']

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function in tinymce.
I suggest you retrieve a node from the tinymce content and search down the node for subnodes.

Comment: Searching down the node is not enough. For example we have some HTML like 

`<div>All <span style="color: red">your <strong>base</strong> are belong </span> to us </div>`

and user clicks in base. We are not getting the color than, or anything else that is applied above.

Comment: in that case your would look into the other direction (up the node)